# Javascript Magento Create Account Preference Error

Tags: javascript, php, forms, magento

I am trying to create a second action on the Create New User Account form on Magento 1.9CE. We need an additional action to build an HTTP string and send to a URL as configured. So far we have built a script to pick up the fields, but this javascript isn't processing because the VarienForm is attached the event handler on document load. Could anybody shed some light on this code we have as to why its not processing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#form-validate').on('submit', function( e )
        {
            var elements = this.elements;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var subscribed = elements.is_subscribed.checked ? "y" : '';
            var bglink = "http://suite9.emarsys.net/u/register_bg.php?owner_id=428212131&f=1481&key_id=3&optin=" + subscribed + "&inp_1=" + elements.firstname.value + "&inp_2=" + elements.lastname.value + "&inp_3=" + elements.email_address.value + "&inp_4=" + elements.year.value + "-" + elements.month.value + "-" + elements.day.value;

            var img = $('<img width="1" height="1" src="'+bglink+'">')
                .on('load error', $.proxy(function()
                {
                    HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.apply(this);
                }, this))
                .appendTo(this);

            return false;
        });
    }, 2000);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you not just rename the the ID of the form and attach your code to that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery in your website may be jquery and prototype are conflict, to fix it:
- first of all you shoud add jQuery.noConflict(); to your website
- the second replace $ equal jQuery 
ex:jQuery(document).ready(function() { })